# EthernetClient not initializing properly

Tags: ethernet, ethernet-shield

I am trying to make a connection with the EthernetClient, but it always fails with code 0. I decided to write a small code just to test if the client ever becomes ready, and as I suspected it does not.

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {0x2A, 0x27, 0x55, 0x08, 0x1E, 0x6A};
IPAddress ip(172, 16, 48, 133);
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  Ethernet.init(10);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {;}

  for (auto link = Ethernet.linkStatus(); link != LinkON; link = Ethernet.linkStatus()) {;}
  Serial.println("Link ON");

  while(!client){
    Serial.println("Client not ready");
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.println("Client ready!");
}

void loop() {}
```

If I try to run the code above, it gets stuck at the "Client not ready" loop, and I can't figure it out what I'm missing for it to work.

Obs.: I have already configured a web server with success with my shield, so I'm guessing the problem is not with it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're evaluating `!client`. This maps to the boolean operator which tells you if it has a connected socket (https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Ethernet/blob/6e9dffa64f6b0eb89607dbb5293dc33be82cc39e/src/Ethernet.h#L232). Since you have not called `connect()` on the client, this will always return false. What actual error do you have in your full sketch?

Comment: Connect returns 0. I've looked the source and found multiple points where it might return 0, so it's hard to diagnose.

Comment: @Maximilian the [reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/IfEthernetClient) says only that it "Indicates if the specified Ethernet client is ready."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `EthernetClient` expects to connect to a remote socket. At no point do you instruct it to connect to a socket, so it never succeeds.

At some point before checking for a connection you need to initiate that connection:

```
// arduino.cc is 100.24.172.113
IPAddress server(100, 24, 172, 113);
client.connect(server, 80);
```

The `if (client)` operation relies on `sockindex` having been assigned a valid value, and that is only ever done either by `EthernetClient::connect()` or by being explicitly set by `EthernetServer::available()`.

Comment: in this [example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/IfEthernetClient) this is done to check if the client is available

Comment: @LucasNoetzold That example makes no sense. Like many on the Arduino website it's complete nonsense. You should only check `if (client)` to confirm a connection has been established. Normally only when using it as an incoming connection to a server.

Comment: As it states in the source code: `// the next function allows us to use the client returned by
// EthernetServer::available() as the condition in an if-statement.
`

Comment: I'll have to find why connect is returning 0 then. Thanks.

Comment: 0 indicates DNS name resolve failure. https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Ethernet/blob/6e9dffa64f6b0eb89607dbb5293dc33be82cc39e/src/EthernetClient.cpp#L38 @LucasNoetzold